# Why can Shor code fix arbitrary errors?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, error-correction, measurement, nielsen-and-chuang

This is taken from Page 434 of Nielsen and Chuang:

> To simplify the analysis, suppose noise of an arbitrary type is occurring on the first
> qubit only; we’ll come back to what happens when noise is affecting other qubits as well.
> Following Chapter 8 we describe the noise by a trace-preserving quantum operation E.
> It is most convenient to analyze error-correction by expanding E in an operator-sum
> representation with operation elements {Ei}.
> Supposing the state of the encoded qubit
> is |ψ⟩ = α|0L⟩ + β|1L⟩.
> To analyze the effects of error-correction it’s easiest to
> focus on the effect error-correction has on a single term in this sum, say Ei|ψ⟩⟨ψ|E†
> i .
> As an operator on the first qubit alone Ei may be expanded as a linear combination of
> the identity, I, the bit flip, X1, the phase flip, Z1, and the combined bit and phase flip,
> X1Z1:
> Ei = ei0I + ei1X1 + ei2Z1 + ei3X1Z1 .
> (10.14)
> The (un-normalized) quantum state Ei|ψ⟩ can thus be written as a superposition of four
> terms, |ψ⟩, X1|ψ⟩, Z1|ψ⟩, X1Z1|ψ⟩. Measuring the error syndrome collapses this super-
> position into one of the four states |ψ⟩, X1|ψ⟩, Z1|ψ⟩ or X1Z1|ψ⟩ from which recovery
> may then be performed by applying the appropriate inversion operation, resulting in the
> final state |ψ⟩. The same is true for all the other operation elements Ei. Thus, error-
> correction results in the original state |ψ⟩ being recovered, despite the fact that the error
> on the first qubit was arbitrary.

From my understanding, $H= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X+Z)$
So if the error's operation is identical to that of the H-gate acting on the qubit, does this mean that on measurement of the error syndrome we have a 50% chance of measuring that the X gate has acted and a 50% chance of measuring that the Z gate has acted?
If yes, doesn't this assume that we will have to pass the same input numerous times until we reach some level of confidence in our obtained probability distribution of $I,X,Z,XZ$ having acted?
How would this work if we could send the bit only once?

Comment: When you perform the syndrome measurement, you will collapse the state as if either the $X$ or $Z$ error occured, as you correctly identified. Up to this point, everything behave really as if only $X$ or only $Z$ error occured. Hence there is no need to repeat anything, you simply correct what you found.

Comment: The way 9 bit code is usually presented is that, *a priori* assume that only 1 error has occurred. This means only X or Z has occurred without us knowing, but not both. (there are 2 separate parts of the circuit to deal with X and Z errors separately, if i recall). This could be a bit confusing at first, because practically we cannot possibly guarantee that "only 1 error has occurred", instead of 2 or 3. But just make that assumption at the beginning, and try to follow the presentation.

Comment: @MarcoFellous-Asiani I don't quite follow. If we perform a measurement and we measure that the X gate has acted, we can easily recify this. My issue is that X gate wasn't the actual operation, infact the H gate has acted and it just so happens that we ended up collapsing the state as if the X gate had acted. It seems like one thing has happened and we have measured another.

Comment: @James Then a set of these Shor codes used parallel could deal with more errors?

Comment: I couldn't remember all the details, it's been awhile... But a great way (if you have not done already) is to look at Hamming codes and other classical error correcting codes first, as the quantum versions (single error correction, multi error corrections) are built using similar concepts from those.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker in quantum mechanics the measurement actively modifies the state, it's not passive. When you perform the syndrome measurement, the Hadamard error will become either an $X$ or $Z$ error. Once you will have done the syndrome measurement everything will behave as if the Hadamard gate was never applied, but either an $X$ or a $Z$ error was actually applied. To be very precise I actually never checked in practice what would happen specifically for Shor code but this is my guess (the syndrome measurement will kill many terms of the density matrix). It is a good exercice to check it.

Comment: @MarcoFellous-Asiani I did the calculations and it works out exactly as you've stated it. Emphasis on this point would be helpful to other learners as well.